# Closing a nested modal window, without the "blurp" sound

Tags: java, javafx

I have 3 windows...

1. `main`: main application,
2. `mod-win1`: a modal window opened from `main`, to edit/create certain objects,
3. `mod-win2`: a modal window opened from `mod-win1`, as a custom file selector.

`mod-win2` is created/opened on a button click on `mod-win1`, this is actioned in the layout controller for this window. `mod-win1` passes a reference to itself to `mod-win2` which `mod-win2` uses to call a close method when needed (on cancel/select).

The problem is that whenever the window is closed, it makes a 'blurp' sound - I know, petty, but it's aggravating me! It's the same sound that the locked window behind the modal window makes if you try to click on it, so I'm thinking it's because I'm going back to the layout controller for the locked window in order to close the current one. All my other modal windows close silently, they're not created from within the layout controller of another window!

Can anyone confirm if this would cause this noise?

Also, is there a way to get a window to close itself (from within its layout controller) so I don't have to access the calling object? 
...or should I be creating an entirely new object to enclose all the file selector functionality and then calling that object (rather than the `mod-win1` layout controller) to close the window?

Comment: Sounds are specific to your operating system, Which one are you using? Also, it would be helpful if you could post some example code demonstrating the issue.

Comment: mmm possibly os specific, I'm on Mac OS X, El Capitan, I'll get it running on my win machine and see if the issue persists.. and good thinking, I'll see if I can mock something simple to demonstrate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

A [Stage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#close--) can be closed any time by calling its close method. I cannot reproduce your blurping sounds on my Windows 10 machine using JDK1.8.0_92. But check out this example:

```
package com.isp.stackoverflow;/**
 * Created by okr on 13.07.2016.
 */

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ModalWindowsClosing extends Application
{

  public static void main( String[] args )
  {
    launch( args );
  }

  @Override
  public void start( Stage primaryStage )
  {
    final Button btn = new Button( "click me!" );
    btn.setOnAction( __ ->
    {
      final Stage dialog = new Stage();
      final Button dialogBtn = new Button( "click me again, fool!" );
      dialogBtn.setOnAction( ___ ->
      {
        final Button closeBtn = new Button( "close dialog" );
        closeBtn.setOnAction( ____ -> dialog.close() );
        final Stage innerDialog = new Stage();
        innerDialog.initOwner( dialog );
        innerDialog.initModality( Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL );
        innerDialog.setScene( new Scene( new StackPane( closeBtn ) ) );
        innerDialog.show();
      } );
      dialog.initOwner( primaryStage );
      dialog.initModality( Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL );
      dialog.setScene( new Scene( new StackPane( dialogBtn ) ) );
      dialog.show();
    } );
    primaryStage.setScene( new Scene( new StackPane( btn ) ) );
    primaryStage.show();
  }
}
```

My guess is, that you have not setup the window owners correctly, but without example code, that is impossible to tell.